# Access Conn Assigns values in Drab

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm going through [Drab Live](https://hexdocs.pm/drab/Drab.Live.html#module-the-conn-case) docs, but still am  unable to access conn assigns in `Drab` Commander socket. I am using the latest version: `{:drab, "~> 0.9.3"}`.

Why is `IO.puts(user)` below returning `nil`?

---

**Drab Commander:**

```ex
defmodule ReviewsWeb.PageCommander do
  use Drab.Commander
  import Ecto.Query
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import ReviewsWeb.Authorize
  import Plug.Conn
​
​
  defhandler like(socket, sender) do
    user = Drab.Core.get_session(socket, :current_user)
    IO.puts(user)
    IO.puts "Hello World!"
  end
end
```

​
**`config.exs`**:
​

```ex
config :drab, Reviews.Repo,
  otp_app: :reviews
​
config :drab, enable_live_scripts: true
​
config :phoenix, :template_engines,
  drab: Drab.Live.Engine
​
config :drab, ReviewsWeb.Endpoint,
  otp_app: :reviews,
  live_conn_pass_through: %{
    assigns: %{
      current_user: true
    },
    private: %{
      phoenix_endpoint: true
    }
  }
```

**`IO.inspect(conn)`**:

```ex
%Plug.Conn{
  adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, :...},
  assigns: %{
    current_user: %{
      __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
      __struct__: Reviews.Accounts.User,
      avatar: %Reviews.Avatar{
        __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "avatars">,
        id: 74,
        image: "1-avatar.jpg",
        inserted_at: ~N[2018-10-27 12:41:09.965086],
        updated_at: ~N[2018-10-27 12:41:09.965092],
        user_id: 1,
        users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>
      },
​
```

Comment: What is the result of `IO.inspect(socket)` and `IO.inspect(sender)`?

Comment: This is the result: https://dpaste.de/XYCQ

Answer (score 0):

**From the [`Drab.Core.get_session/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/drab/Drab.Core.html#get_session/2) documentation:**

> You must explicit [sic] which session keys you want to access in
>   `:access_session` option in `use Drab.Commander` or globally, in
>   `config.exs`:
>
> ```ex
> config :drab, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
>   access_session: [:user_id]
> ```

---

So you need to allow your `:current_user` key in the global config or the `use` macro call:

```ex
use Drab.Commander, access_session: [:current_user]
```

---

<sup>Also [see the discussion around this](https://elixirforum.com/t/drab-how-to-get-a-conn-value/15168) on ElixirForum by the creator of Drab.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I tried first adding access session in commander and later config, however: user = Drab.Core.get_session(socket, :current_user)  IO.inspect(user) still shows nil. Commander and Config: https://dpaste.de/nxGY

Comment: But IO.inspect(socket) now shows current_user (also as nil) https://dpaste.de/PRBw , normally I access current_user by conn.assigns.current_user.id. Maybe I need to specify "assigns.current_user" in access_session?

Comment: This is my Plug.Conn. I also tried replacing current_user with user_id but still nil in commander. https://dpaste.de/dvNQ